# Unable to compile C program using ALSA library, linker not finding library functions

Tags: linux, alsa

I am fairly new to Linux and ALSA. I am trying to compile a simple program to enumerate sound devices on a Raspberry Pi 4 running the Raspberry Pi OS based on Debian Bullseye. The code (which I copied from an example on the web) is:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <alsa/pcm.h>

int main() {
  int val;

  printf("ALSA library version: %s\n", SND_LIB_VERSION_STR);

  char **hints;
  /* Enumerate sound devices */
  int err = snd_device_name_hint(-1, "pcm", (void***)&hints);
  if (err != 0)
     return 0;//Error! Just return

  char** n = hints;
  while (*n != NULL) {

      char *name = snd_device_name_get_hint(*n, "NAME");

      if (name != NULL && 0 != strcmp("null", name)) {
          //Copy name to another buffer and then free it
          free(name);
      }
      n++;
  }//End of while

  //Free hint buffer
  snd_device_name_free_hint((void**)hints);
 
  return 0;
}
```

I installed the ALSA libraries using

```
$ sudo apt install libasound
$ sudo apt install libasound2
$ sudo apt install libasound-dev
```

when I try to compile, I get:

```
$ gcc -lasound  test1.c -o test1
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccUWxojL.o: in function `main':
test1.c:(.text+0x28): undefined reference to `snd_device_name_hint'
/usr/bin/ld: test1.c:(.text+0x60): undefined reference to `snd_device_name_get_hint'
/usr/bin/ld: test1.c:(.text+0xb8): undefined reference to `snd_device_name_free_hint'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

so it seems that the linker is finding the library, but can't find the functions that I need.

I checked to make sure that libasound.so is in /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf, and then I checked to make sure that those functions were present, which they were:

```
$ nm -D /usr/lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libasound.so | grep snd_device_name*
0002f358 T snd_device_name_free_hint@@ALSA_0.9
0002f898 T snd_device_name_get_hint@@ALSA_0.9
0002f394 T snd_device_name_hint@@ALSA_0.9
```

Anyway, I'm not sure where to go from here.  Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why does the order in which libraries are linked sometimes cause errors in GCC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45135/why-does-the-order-in-which-libraries-are-linked-sometimes-cause-errors-in-gcc)

Comment: It seems unlikely that there are circular dependencies here because there is only one source file and one library being used.

Comment: Agreed there aren't circular dependencies, but the order of arguments matters.  That's covered in the question I linked.

Comment: Thanks for your help with this. I reread the link that you sent, and it is clear that it deals with circular references between multiple libraries, in which case the order does matter. Not sure why this applies to my case where there is only one library, but I rearranged my gcc command-line so that "-lasound" is at the end of the line and now it is compiling. Thanks again.